# React Hooks: Rerender even though state didn't change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement a simple Header component where the header would hide after reaching a certain scroll position.

I came up with the following solution and thought that a rerender of the `Header` component would only happen if the value of `headerState` actually changed which is not what's happening. The component will rerender on every change of the scroll position, even when `setHeaderState` isn't even called.

What am I missing here? Is it rerendering because I'm using `useWindowScroll` and can I avoid it somehow?

```
 import { useWindowScroll } from "react-use";

const useHeaderState = () => {
  const [ headerState, setHeaderState ] = React.useState(0);

  const { y } = useWindowScroll();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (y > 50 && headerState !== 1) {
      setHeaderState(1);
    }
  }, [y, headerState]);

  return headerState;
}

const Header: React.FC = () => {
  const headerState = useHeaderState();

  console.log("rerender");

  return (
    <header
      className={cn(
        "fixed top-0 left-0 w-full text-white z-30 transition-transform transition-250",
        headerState === 1 && "-translate-16",
      )}
    >
      <div className="bg-gray-900 h-16 md:h-32">header</div>
    </header>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue like you said is that `useWindowScroll` internally is likely calling `setState` on its own `useState` hook.

Generally, it shouldn't be an issue that a component re-renders? Is there a problem with this?

However, an option is to move the `useHeaderState` hook to the parent and then use [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to memoize the `Header` and only re-render if the props have changed.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import { useWindowScroll } from "react-use";

const useHeaderState = () => {
  const [headerState, setHeaderState] = React.useState(0);

  const { y } = useWindowScroll();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (y > 50 && headerState !== 1) {
      setHeaderState(1);
    }
  }, [y, headerState]);

  return headerState;
};

const Header: React.FC<{ headerState: number }> = React.memo(props => {
  console.log("rerender");

  return (
    <header className={props.headerState === 1 && "class"}>
      <div className="bg-gray-900 h-16 md:h-32">header</div>
    </header>
  );
});

function App() {
  const headerState = useHeaderState();

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 2000 }}>
      <Header headerState={headerState} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: That would make my App component rerender on every scroll position change though, wouldn't it? In general I just try to avoid unnecessary rerenders where possible. A simple header might not have a big performance impact but as my app get's more complex it might? I guess in my example, using the window scroll event directly instead of using another hook might be the simplest. I just thought that my Header component only rerenders when the `headerState` value changes but apparently that's not how it works

Comment: I wouldn't prematurely optimize. I would keep things simple. Introducing complexity will inevitably come back to bite you. `React.memo` is intended only to be used when there is a clear performance problem (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo). Instead, I would not worry about this unnecessary re-render unless you notice a performance problem and measure it with React DevTools (or browser devtools) and pin-point the cause and optimize that problem. I think this is a pretty good overview on this topic: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-slow-render-before-you-fix-the-re-render

Answer (score 1):

Re-rendering is indeed because of `useWindowScroll`.
As seen in [source](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useWindowScroll.ts), `useWindowScroll` calls setState every time window scrolls.

To avoid wasted rendering, you can listen to window scroll yourself instead of using `useWindowScroll`, like:

```js
const useHeaderState = () => {
  const [headerState, setHeaderState] = React.useState(0);

  const frame = useRef(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(frame.current);
      frame.current = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        if (window.pageYOffset > 50 && headerState !== 1) {
          setHeaderState(1);
        }
      });
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handler, {
      capture: false,
      passive: true
    });

    return () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(frame.current);
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handler);
    };
  });

  return headerState;
};
```